# Iteration question over series of numbers

Tags: python

```
def get_valid_user_input():
    user_input = input("Enter a number, or leave blank for infinite loop: ")
    if user_input == "":
        return -1
    try:
        return int(user_input)
    except ValueError:
        print("Error! Please enter a number or leave blank.")
        return get_valid_user_input()

my_object = my_func(n=get_valid_user_input())
while True:
    try:
        print(next(my_object))
    except StopIteration:
        print("End of Iteration")
        break
```

Hi I have the above code thanks to seon.

I want the code to iterate up to 10 times counting as it goes.

1 3 6 9 etc until it reaches the 10th iteration

At this point I want a question to be asked do you want to continue the iteration.which would result in am infinite loop..if no then the loop breaks and then an option is sent asking again how many iterations would you like..user enters 3 iterations 1 3 6 9 is printed

I'm sorry if I'm asking too many questions about the same topic but any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect `next(my_object)` to work? `my_object` is an `int`... `int` objects aren't iterators, thus `next(my_object)` will raise a `TypeError`...

Comment: What are the rules for your output?

Comment: User enters 10 for example..it iterates 10 times prints out a sequence of numbers 1 3 6 9 12 15 up until 10 iterations are reached..anything above 10 it prompts the user Yes to continue which carries out an infinite loop of numbers in triangular sequence...3 6 9 12 a  so on..if they enter no the loop breaks and the loop stops returning a prompt asking how many iterations the user would like to enter..so the user enters 5...it then prints 5 iteration of numbers